# Exclude a method to Proguard obfuscation

Tags: android, proguard

Proguard obfuscation renames the methods and classes of my android source after the exportation, I need that a specific method in a specific class mantain is name also after the build with proguard.

How could I perform this?

For example:

assuming that I want to preserve the name of the method `myMethod` in the class `MyClass` of package `my.package.android.com` How should I write the `-keep` modifier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create ProGuard config file using `-keep` option with specified class name you want to be ommited during obfuscating.

See ProGuard docs: http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html

> -keep [,modifier,...] class_specification
>
> ```
> Specifies classes and class members (fields and methods) to be preserved as entry points to your code.
> ```

Comment: thanks for the answer I haven't understand the right syntax: assuming that I want to preserve the name of the method myMethod in the classMyClass of package my.package.android.com How should I write?